# Is there compatibility consideration in choosing encoding scheme for 100GbE?

Tags: ethernet-phy

I encounted a frequency of `161.1328125`Mhz recently, and I digged a bit about its origin (because the figure seems odd at first glance). It seems that for 10GbE standards, it uses 64/66b encoding, so to achieve 10Gbps, the signal baudrate has to be `10*66/64=10.3125`(Gbaud). And `10.3125G/64=161.1328125M`, so this gives a reason for `161.1328125M` that it's a base freqeuncy for 10GbE signals. And there are 161.132M crystal oscillators used in production as I see some on my PCIe cards.

For 100GbE, it seems that the same base frequency pops up again: it's said that 100GbE uses 256/257b encoding with 514/528 RS-FEC, so the signal baudrate has to be `100*257/256*528/514=103.125`(Gbaud), which is 10 times the baudrate of 10GbE. So the same base frequency `161.1328125`MHz can be used.

Actually `64/66` is exactally equal to `256/257*514/528`. What a coincidence! I am guessing that, when people were choosing the encoding/FEC scheme for 100GbE, they deliberately chosen these numbers (256/257 and 514/528) such that baudrate of 100GbE is 10 times that of 10GbE (thus the 161.1328125M crystal oscillators can also be used).

Does my guess make sense?